# How to Import Librarary in android

Tags: android

I used this project on github

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer

this project consists Library for work it

http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/

How to Import in Eclipse and then use it on the  Properties of Projects

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this.

If in the package, there is a `.jar`, you have to add them into `Libs` folder of your project and import them to your java `class`.

You can also `import` the entire project as an `project` in your IDE and edit you project `properties` to link it as a library.

Comment: Also, this may help you! http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

Comment: I must import Library  to Eclipse and then use it on  : You can also import the entire project as an project in your IDE and edit you project properties to link it as a library. My Problem that project cannot Import in Eclipse

Comment: I want  Import this Library to Eclipse  :  http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/